# usage of memorize in Present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

George is doing his homework today. He needs to memorize 30 French words.

Is the verb "memorize" used correctly in the following two sentences?

> George has memorized 30 French words for an hour.

> George has been memorizing 30 French words for an hour.

In my opinion, *George has memorized* indicates a completion. So it doesn't go with "for an hour".

On the other hand, *George has been memorizing* indicates an ongoing activity. It can go with a duration and fits the context, but it doesn't go well with "30 French words". We don't say *George has been reading **five** books for a month*, for example. It sounds like George was reading the five books simultaneously. Rather, we'd delete the words "five".

Comment: Both sound odd, in my opinion. You could say _George has memorised 30 French words in the past hour_ or _George has been working for an hour to memorise 30 French words_.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think my understanding in the OP is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.